# Dealership change the ARP

Tags: contract-law, breach-of-contract

I purchase a 2021 Chevy Suburban from a Dealership, my contract was with one bank, when it was time to pay my first payment another bank had the loan.   I didn't notice that ARP was change until my 3rd payment.  I reach out to that bank, they sent me the contract. It was a totally different contract than what I sign. The ARP had change from .41 to .49 and someone else had sign that contract. It was not my signature, I sign everything electronically and the contract the bank has is handwritten. The bank said I need to talk to the dealership. Can I sue?

Comment: ARP? You mean APR?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably illegal. Forging a signature is illegal, indeed it is a crime. If you signed a contract with bank A with a certain interest rate, bank A can sell that contract to bank B, but neither A nor B can change the terms (e.g. increase the interest charge). There might be some sketchy clause in the contract that you did sign which they think allows that to change the terms unilaterally under some condition (e.g. "we reserve the right to sell thig contract to a third parts who may increase the interest by X amount"), but such a clause would most likely violate law recarding unlawful acts in car sales (example from [Washington state](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=46.70.180)). It is very hard to understand why the bank would tell you to talk to the dealership, if you actually had a contract with the bank. That suggests that you actually did not have a contract with the bank, you signed a form supplied by the car dealer and the form say something like "we will try to get you an interest rate at .41%". Still, they must offer you the opportunity to accept or reject the alternative rate.

Unfortunately, by paying the charge and not complaining, you may be considered to have accepted the modified term. That does not excuse forging your signature, so talking to the dealership is one possibility. If this is in the US, your state's attorney general might also have an interest in criminal behavior by a car dealership.